# GitHub - Fork a repo and implement its pull requests

Tags: git, github

I've come across a useful repo, but it's unmaintained and there are some good pull requests with bug fixes etc. that haven't been implemented. Is there anyway I can fork the repo and implement the pull requests into my forked repo?

Comment: This looks relevant: https://gist.github.com/piscisaureus/3342247

Comment: Yes, there are multiple ways. I would suggest you first simply fork the project and ask the authors of the pull requests if they could pull request to your repo, too. If that fails, see the link in the comment above.

Answer (score 0):

Forking the repo won't duplicate those pull requests, but nothing prevents you to merge the branches from which those pull requests are done.

For instance, this [pull request](https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI/pull/444) shows:

```
DveMac wants to merge 1 commit into Semantic-Org:master from DveMac:master
```

You can add a remote 'DevMac' to your local clone of your fork:

```
git remote add DevMac https://github.com/DveMac/Semantic-UI
```

And then

```
git fetch DveMac
git merge DveMac/master
```

If you want a more direct way (to get *all* pull requests instead of picking just one), [the gist](https://gist.github.com/piscisaureus/3342247) suggested by [Ismail Badawi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/281108/ismail-badawi) is a way to fetch branches from the `/pull` namespace, and put those in a `/pr` namespace.

Answer (score 0):

**To avoid link impermanence I have copied the solution from [the gist](https://gist.github.com/piscisaureus/3342247) linked twice in this thread:**

Locate the section for your github remote in the `.git/config` file. It looks like this:

```
[remote "origin"]
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
    url = git@github.com:joyent/node.git
```

Now add the line `fetch = +refs/pull/*/head:refs/remotes/origin/pr/*` to this section. Obviously, change the github url to match your project's URL. It ends up looking like this:

```
[remote "origin"]
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
    url = git@github.com:joyent/node.git
    fetch = +refs/pull/*/head:refs/remotes/origin/pr/*
```

Now fetch all the pull requests:

```
$ git fetch origin
From github.com:joyent/node
 * [new ref]         refs/pull/1000/head -> origin/pr/1000
 * [new ref]         refs/pull/1002/head -> origin/pr/1002
 * [new ref]         refs/pull/1004/head -> origin/pr/1004
 * [new ref]         refs/pull/1009/head -> origin/pr/1009
...
```

To check out a particular pull request:

```
$ git checkout pr/999
Branch pr/999 set up to track remote branch pr/999 from origin.
Switched to a new branch 'pr/999'
```